# Get something like Resultset from data file

Tags: java, file

I want to read a delimiter-separated or fixed-width file (of defined layout), and want to get something like a Resultset through which I can iterate throgh the record.

Is there any reliable library for doing this? If not then can anyone please suggest me how I should proceed? An example code snippet will be very helpful to me.

Comment: Use [`Files.lines`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) to get a `Stream` of the lines. Process each line to an `Object` representing that line. Loop away...

Answer (score 1):

You can use java ios to iterate each line in the text file and then implement your own logic to split the line and do as desired.

```
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
//input file
File inputFile = new File("c:/hadoop/sample.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
String s = null;
while ((s = (br.readLine())) != null) {
    //check each line and do the logic may be split or based on the requirement   
        String cols[] =s.split("|");

}
}
```

Comment: Please make sure you close your resources using a `try-with-resources`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Stream<String> lines(Path path)
                            throws IOException
```

Read all lines from a file as a Stream. Bytes from the file are decoded into characters using the UTF-8 charset.

This method works as if invoking it were equivalent to evaluating the expression:

```
 Files.lines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

**Parameters:**
path - the path to the file

**Returns:** the lines from the file as a Stream

**Throws:**

**IOException** - if an I/O error occurs opening the file

**SecurityException** - In the case of the default provider, and a security manager is installed, the checkRead method is invoked to check read access to the file.

**Since:** 1.8

[`Files.lines(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) expects a `Path` argument and returns a `Stream<String>`. 
This is Java 8, so you can use lambda expressions or method references to provide a `Consumer` argument.

```
public class FixedWidthFile {

    public static void main(String JavaLatte[]) {
        Path path = Paths.get("/home/sample.txt");
        try {
            Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path);
            lines.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
    }
}
```

Reference: [Class Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-)

Comment: I'm going to have to down vote this as it does not properly close the `Stream` and has an empty `catch`. Whilst the former is a serious error, and explicitly mentioned in the javadoc: _If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the try-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the stream's close method is invoked after the stream operations are completed._ The latter is completely unforgivable in code designed to teach. Always, at least add an `ex.printStackTrace(System.err)`.